# make a entity class rows read-only in JPA

Tags: java, orm, jpa, entity-relationship, eclipselink

I m able to get values using JPA when i have only mapped one table

Now when i have gone for mapping related tables i get the error

```
  Only one may be defined as writable, all others must be specified read-only.
  Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToOneMapping[userId1]
```

I m using [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.1.v20100213-r6600)

In one of the child tables i have this code

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "albumId")
private Collection<Images> imagesCollection;
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "User_ID")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Roleuser userId;
@JoinColumn(name = "album_image", referencedColumnName = "image_id")
@ManyToOne
private Images albumImage;
@JoinColumn(name = "album_image", referencedColumnName = "image_id")
@ManyToOne
private Images albumImage1;
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "User_ID")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Roleuser userId1;
```

What changes i have to do in this code to make the fields read-only?

or are there any better workaround for not making these fields read only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two ManyToOne relationships using the same foreign key field.  This does not make sense, they will be the same object?

```
@JoinColumn(name = "album_image", referencedColumnName = "image_id")
@ManyToOne
private Images albumImage;
@JoinColumn(name = "album_image", referencedColumnName = "image_id")
@ManyToOne
private Images albumImage1;
```

You should have two different foreign key fields, i.e. albumImage and albumImage1.

Comment: went with openJPA with no issues or so do i think... may be bugging around later... well i have one more question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567438/select-from-two-tables-using-jpql

Comment: i dont know much about JPA but the entity classes i generated with netbeans and they are same with openJPA...

Comment: netbeans generated the classes...well why did netbeans generate two references of a single relation...should i file a bug for netbeans...

Comment: to make one of the JoinColumns read-only, set insertable/updateable=false in the annotation.  But you mapping still does not make any sense...

Comment: Also, please log a bug for this issue, that we should probably just log a warning instead of throwing an error.